# HTML: Render .svg file in line

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to render an `.svg` file but it is not positioned in a nice way. It is not rendered inline, but above the line. Padding or margins don't help.

```css
p svg {
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p><svg width="1792" height="1792" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1113 974q13 0 97.5 44t89.5 53q2 5 2 15 0 33-17 76-16 39-71 65.5t-102 26.5q-57 0-190-62-98-45-170-118t-148-185q-72-107-71-194v-8q3-91 74-158 24-22 52-22 6 0 18 1.5t19 1.5q19 0 26.5 6.5t15.5 27.5q8 20 33 88t25 75q0 21-34.5 57.5t-34.5 46.5q0 7 5 15 34 73 102 137 56 53 151 101 12 7 22 7 15 0 54-48.5t52-48.5zm-203 530q127 0 243.5-50t200.5-134 134-200.5 50-243.5-50-243.5-134-200.5-200.5-134-243.5-50-243.5 50-200.5 134-134 200.5-50 243.5q0 203 120 368l-79 233 242-77q158 104 345 104zm0-1382q153 0 292.5 60t240.5 161 161 240.5 60 292.5-60 292.5-161 240.5-240.5 161-292.5 60q-195 0-365-94l-417 134 136-405q-108-178-108-389 0-153 60-292.5t161-240.5 240.5-161 292.5-60z"/></svg> Whatsapp
</p>
```

Font awesome or `display: flex;` could solve this problem but I can't use them in this particular case. Is there any way to position it properly? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `vertical-align:middle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property to your SVG. I think a value of `text-bottom` gives the best result in this case.

```css
p svg {
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

p {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p><svg width="1792" height="1792" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1113 974q13 0 97.5 44t89.5 53q2 5 2 15 0 33-17 76-16 39-71 65.5t-102 26.5q-57 0-190-62-98-45-170-118t-148-185q-72-107-71-194v-8q3-91 74-158 24-22 52-22 6 0 18 1.5t19 1.5q19 0 26.5 6.5t15.5 27.5q8 20 33 88t25 75q0 21-34.5 57.5t-34.5 46.5q0 7 5 15 34 73 102 137 56 53 151 101 12 7 22 7 15 0 54-48.5t52-48.5zm-203 530q127 0 243.5-50t200.5-134 134-200.5 50-243.5-50-243.5-134-200.5-200.5-134-243.5-50-243.5 50-200.5 134-134 200.5-50 243.5q0 203 120 368l-79 233 242-77q158 104 345 104zm0-1382q153 0 292.5 60t240.5 161 161 240.5 60 292.5-60 292.5-161 240.5-240.5 161-292.5 60q-195 0-365-94l-417 134 136-405q-108-178-108-389 0-153 60-292.5t161-240.5 240.5-161 292.5-60z"/></svg> Whatsapp
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! I try all the vertical-align attributes and see which one fits best. Sometimes it's `vertical-align: text-bottom;`, sometimes `vertical-align: sub;`